# How to return all checkbox values to a string using a floating icon

Tags: java, android, android-listview, return, android-arrayadapter

Im not sure how to return values from my listview which includes checkboxes. Im fairly new to Android and ArrayAdapters in general so please bear with me.

Here is my list adapter, having two text views and a checkbox

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/NumberView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/NameView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/NumberView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/NameView"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

A button on activity_mail calls this:

```
 public void grabthecontacts(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.selectcontacts);
    populateListView(view);
}
```

Now im not sure what do to after this next function, this is what creates and populates the list, but how do I get the results?

Here is my populatelistview function, which pulls all the persons contacts and then puts it into an adapter

```
public void populateListView(View view) {
    try {
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            list.add(new Person(name, phoneNumber));
        }
        phones.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter = new myListAdapter();
    ListView listview2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactlistview);
    listview2.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public class myListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {

    public myListAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.da_item, list);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.da_item, parent, false);
        }
        // Find person wot work with
        Person currentperson = list.get(position);

        // Fill the view
        TextView nameboxview = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.NameView);
        nameboxview.setText(currentperson.getName());

        TextView numberboxview = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.NumberView);
        numberboxview.setText(currentperson.getPhone());



        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use it to select from that list of contacts @MsYvette

Comment: Thank you so much :) @MsYvette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own `Person` class which will have a `boolean` instance variable which will tell if the particular item has been selected or not.

```
/**
 * Created by Pankaj Nimgade on 19-12-2015.
 */
public class Person {

    private boolean isChecked;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        isChecked = checked;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Make a `ArrayList` of this class type and populate your `ListView`.

make little change in your Adapter... add following code which will keep track of what items were selected.

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
   person.setChecked(true);
}
```

after your listview is populated

```
ArrayList<Person> searchList = searchList(list);
```

following is the code to look for the items which was checked.

```
private ArrayList<Person> searchList(ArrayList<Person> list) {
    ArrayList<Person> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).isChecked()) {
            tempList.add(list.get(i));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```